# Custom design for products from a category

Tags: category-products, layout-update

I want to set a different view for all the products from a category. I am using the default functionality from admin-> category-> custom design-> custom layout update:

```
<reference name="product.info">
<action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/apparel_view.phtml</template></action>
```

I have tried the solution from [Custom category design](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7124/custom-category-designs-wont-apply-without-category-url-slug) but I couldn't manage to make it work. If I go to the product page using the category in link it is fine (like http://xxxx.ro/store/apparel-accesories/mens-graphic-t-shirt), but otherwise the default view is seen(like http://xxxx.ro/store/mens-graphic-t-shirt).

Comment: Actually my problem is that my product is in 2 categories: store and apparel-accesories. I set the custom layout only for apparel-accesories, but my product can also be seen using store category. In store I have also other categories for which I am using a different layout than for apparel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK..I ended up extending class `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View` method `initProductLayout` with `$update->addHandle('PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_'.$product->getAttributeSetId());` and then set for my attribute set id the layout updates. Now it works for all situations...

```
    <PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_10>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/apparel-view.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/apparel_view.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_10>
```

Comment: BTW there is a better solution to add such a layout handle. You do not need a rewrite, you can do it with an observer as described here: http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/creating-custom-layout-handles/